# How to write at-sign inside attribut in ASP.NET Web Page with Razor?

Tags: asp.net, razor, escaping

I have a HTML like this:

```
<img src="..." alt="Find me on twitter as @username" />
```

However, that gives an error that variable "username" does not exist. Outside of HTML attributes, at-sign can be escaped as `@@` but that doesn't work inside attributes. What's the right syntax?

Comment: As far as I know it's the same.

Comment: The same as what? Single `@` will crash with "unknown variable", `@@` will crash with ""@" is not valid at the start of a code block.  Only identifiers, keywords, comments, "(" and "{" are valid.".

Comment: @nemesv No MVC, just Web Pages. Version 2.0.

Comment: @FlorimMaxhuni Doesn't work, still getting this error: "CS0103: The name 'username' does not exist in the current context.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In MVC3 (e.g Razor 1.0) the double at e.g `@@` is working:

```
<img src="..." alt="Find me on twitter as @@username" />
```

But in MVC4 (e.g Razor 2.0) something has changed and it's not working anymore (maybe it's a bug...).

So because it's only allowed to have a code block inside an attribute you need to write a code block with `@(...)` from where you can return the `@`:

```
<img src="..." alt="Find me on twitter as @("@username")" />
```

or

```
<img src="..." alt="Find me on twitter as @("@")username" />
```

As far as I know Web Pages 2.0 uses Razor 2.0.

Answer (score 1):

Why not html escape the @-sign?

```
<img src="..." alt="Find me on twitter as &#64;username" />
```

Comment: Yes that's the non-Razor solution. I know about it, I'd just like to know how @-sign escaping works inside attributes.